# NSString and NSMutableString concatenation

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, concatenation

I have three strings (a `NSString`, a `NSMutableString`, and another `NSString`) which I need to concatenate into a mutable string, in that order, to display as the source for a UIWebView. Comming from a PHP/JavaScript/HTML background, my knowledge of concatenation is pretty much this:

```
var concatenatedString = string1 + string2 + string3;
```

I presume that sort of thing won't work in Objective-C, so I'm wondering how to go about pulling them all together properly.

To give a bit of setting for this, the first string (`NSString`) is the header and canvas element of a web page, the second string (`NSMutableString`) is javascript from a text field that the user can define to manipulate the canvas element, and the third string (`NSString`) is the end tags of the web page.

Also, rather than initially creating the `NSMutableString`, should I just referance the `UITextView.text` to the get the user's text when concatenating the whole thing, or should I pull the text from the `UITextView` first?

Comment: I don't get the very last paragraph you wrote. Can you clarify?

Comment: @NJones answer kind of explains what I meant, have a quick look. Overall, it answers the whole question, in an efficient way. Thanks a heap for your answer too though, it certainly helps as well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other two answers are correct in that they answer the question as you asked it. But by your description of what you want to do there is a much easier way. Use a format.

Assuming `string1` and `string3` will always be the same and only `string2` will change,which is what it sounds like you are doing you can write something like this.

```
static NSString *formatString = @"String1Text%@String3Text";
NSString *completeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:formatString,self.myTextFieldName.text];
NSLog(@"%@",completeString);
```

The `%@` in the format says to insert the description of the object following the format.(The description of an `NSString` is the `stringValue`.)
Assuming you have a `UITextField` named `myTextFieldName`, that currently contains the text '`String2Text`' Then this will be the output:

'`String1TextString2TextString3Text`'

In this way you only create 1 instance of an NSString format for the whole class no matter how many times you call this code.

To me it sounds like you don't need a mutable string at all. Feel free to leave a comment if I misunderstood anything.

Response to comment:

I'm not sure how you are implementing 'moves to test it out again' but, let's say you have a button named 'testJavaScript'. The IBAction method connected to that button would have the first two lines in it. So each time you pushed the button it would make a new formatted NSString filled with the current contents of the textfield. Once this string was formed it could not be changed. But it won't matter since next time it will make another.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is perfect!
I'm making it mutable so that it can change if the user goes back, edits their javascript and moves to test it out again it will change. I was under the impression that if the string isn't mutable it can't be changed later?

Comment: Thats pretty much it, this is an iOS app, on the first screen the text view and test button are there, when the test button is pressed the variable is created and we move to the next view in the navigation stack, which has the web view that uses the variable. The user can press back at the top of the screen to return to the text view and edit further.

I get what you mean with the NSStrings now though, and can now see why I don't need to use a mutable string after all. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

```
NSMutableString *concatenatedString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", string1, string2, string3] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: +1 yep. There's also an `-appendString:` method on `NSMutableString`, but this way is more idiomatic.

Comment: In theory, since NSMutableString is a subclass of NSString, one should be able to do `[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:...`.  But I've never tried it.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *concatenatedString = [string1 stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@%@", string2, string3];
```

You can make the resulting string mutable (if you really need to) by adding mutableCopy as shown in the answer by @Vinnie.